# The sum of the numbers inside the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

The function takes an array and returns an array of the sum of the numbers inside the object. Where is the mistake?

```
const car = [
  {  
    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mitsubishi",
    "price":"93 000", 
    "constructor":"Bar John",
    "door":"3",
    "country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mercedes-benz",
    "price":"63 000", 
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight",
    "people":"63"
  }
 ];

function tur(car){
   return car.map(()=>{
      return  car.reduce((a, b) => {  return (parseInt(a)) + (parseInt(b))});
   })
}
```

Comment: You forgot to provide an initial value for the `reduce`

Comment: You are trying to add objects together. E.g. in the first call of reduce, `a` will be the object representing the BMW, and `b` will be the object representing the Mitsubishi.

Comment: Inside the `reduce()` method, `b` is an object, there is no sense then on call `parseInt(b)`. Also I suggest to add the expected output you are trying to get from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` can't deal with the spaces, plus you're iterating over whole objects so you'll need to pull out the property:

```
cars.map(car => parseInt(car.price.replace(/\s/g, ''),10)).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

As a bonus it's already parsed by the time it gets to the next stage. Don't forget to specify a base (10) to your `parseInt` or it'll interpret things like `0x20` as hex.

Call your main structure `cars` as it's a series of objects, not one.

Ideally you'd clean up the price data before going to this function in the first place.